Proving that for every solution to the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - x$ there exists some $c$ so that the solution does not exist for $x < c$
For the ordinary differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - x,$$
how can I prove that every solution to this ODE has a “starting time” (if I think of ( x ) as time) before which it does not exist? In other words, how can I show that every integral curve is asymptotic to a vertical straight line to its left?

Did you solve the equation ?

I'm no expert with ODEs, but this equation doesn't seem to have an easily computable solution. An idea as to how to tackle the problem might be to show that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ diverges to infinity in finite (negative) time? I'm not sure how one could go about doing this...though I'd imagine it's certainly possible to do.

@ClaudeLeibovici no i had only drawn the direction field of the ODE

Why not to put in the post ?

Assume that a solution exists on $(-\infty, B]$. Set $b = \min(B, -1)$. Then
$$
  y'(x) \ge y(x)^2 + 1
$$
for $x \le b$. For $a < b$ is
$$
 \pi \ge \arctan(y(b)) - \arctan(y(a)) = \int_a^b \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2 + 1} \, dx
\ge \int_a^b 1 \, dx = b - a
$$
and that is not possible: The left-hand side is bounded, but the right-hand side grows to $+\infty$ for $a \to -\infty$.
(The idea is to compare $y$ with the solutions of $\tilde y' = \tilde y^2 + 1$, which are of the form $\tilde y(x) = \tan(x+c)$ and exist only on finite intervals.)

This is a Riccati type equation. Use the standard substitution $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ to find the second order linear DE
$$
u''-xu=0.
$$
Discuss this as Airy equation or as general oscillator equation applying the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem. For $x<-1$ there is at least one root in every interval of length $\pi$. Where $u$ has a root, $y$ has a pole that can serve as end point of the domain of a ODE solution.
